# Excavated large rocks in concrete mix for staircase

Tags: concrete, stairs

In the process of prepping for my basement staircase, I excavated a fair amount of dirt and some rocks (size between baseball and football). Would it be OK to put some of those rocks (rinsed clean, of course) into the form together with the concrete mix to save on concrete (both material and labor, but especially the latter since I'm mixing manually in a tub)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's commonly done to dispose of stones, but too many in one area or in a line can cause weakness. The bond between the concrete and the stone can let go, resulting in thin areas. Voids can also result below the stones.

Try to keep at least 4" of clean concrete above the stones and work the concrete down around them well. It should be just fine.

Comment: One of the major causes of cracked concrete is sudden change in thickness. The thickness change at stairs is tapered. The thickness change next to a football sized rock is drastic and will likely cause problems in the future. I strongly recommend rebar (temperature steel) both directions plus one bar in tapered area.

Answer (score 3):

No, it’s not acceptable to use random sized rocks in concrete mix.

Concrete is not a mix of random materials. If those rocks end up near the surface of the pour, you’ll have large cracks around the rocks due to bonding (or lack there of) and weakening of the pour.

If you’ve over excavated and need fill, use them at the bottom of the pour by pounding them into your base.(Try to get them level with the surrounding base so you don’t have projections into your pour.)  This will give you a solid base and reduce the quantity of concrete required.

Btw, if you’re using rebar, those rocks could jeopardize required bonding on the rebar too.

Comment: I'd agree, but stairs are a different animal. The pour is very thick in spots.